# how to redirect using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Super-simple AngularJS app I'm trying to build, to accept credentials into two text boxes, then use two-way binding to redirect on a button click to a url which includes the two variables in it.

My problem is, I can get it working for a simple

```
<a href=...>
```

(or maybe ng-href=...) but for some reason, no matter what I do, I can't get a redirect using a

```
<button>
```

I've tried a lot of variations, but here's what I'm trying to do

```
<button ng-click="$location.path('http://example.com/login.jsp?un={{username}}&pw={{password}}')" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Log In!</button>
```

I CAN get it working if I call a function in a controller, but this is such a simple thing, I'd like to get it done on the page if possible.

Also, as a side-question, what are the security concerns of logging into a site like this?

**
Edit:  The part that confuses me is, this works (just without two-way binding working):

```
<button onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com/{{username}}');">
```

I'd expect that changing onClick to ng-click would give me the same behaviour, but with two-way binding.

**Re-Edit / Solution
Alright, so I finally got a workable solution.

I have NO idea why the Button tag won't work to give this behaviour, as stated above, but here's the working code.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/login.jsp?un={{username}}&pw={{password}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Log In!</a>
```

By giving it the same class as I intended to use for the button, the text shows up looking like a button, just the same.

Comment: You can't get it to work, because `$location` isn't in the scope, so it's not accessible in your view.

Comment: Is it possible with any other variation of window or location?

It's odd, because I can get a redirect using normal javascript using onClick, but that doesn't give me my two-way binding.  So changing it to ng-click I'd expect it to act the same, but with two-way binding, but then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: _"I'd like to get it done on the page if possible."_ This would simply be bad design. Use a function in your controller!

Comment: Yes, and you should only have a single space after a period.  But when I put two spaces, it doesn't really matter, unless I'm applying to a position which would care.

Likewise, I understand that 'best practices' would make what should be a single-page, no-controller AngularJS example into a multi-file, multi-folder setup, with everything encapsulated within generic functions, etc. 

What I'm trying to get at is, why does onClick and ng-click act different in this case?  Two-way binding works without a controller, and window.open works without angular, why don't the two work together?

Comment: You should disable the link until the `{{username}}` and `{{password}}` are set, and when doing dyanmic urls like this is good practice to use `ng-href` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) although it may not matter in this case because it appears to depend on user input so it wont help you (i.e. you need enable/disable).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put a method on your controller to do the redirect and have that called form the `ng-click` on your button.

Markup:

```
<button ng-click="goLogin()">Log in</button>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.form = {
        username: null,
        password: null
    };

    $scope.goLogin = function() {
        $location.url('http://test.com/login.jsp?un='+ $scope.form.username +'&pw="+ $scope.form.password);
    };
})
```

Also note you want to call `$location.url()` not `path()`

OR...

Add `$location` to your scope and call `url({{newUrl}})`:

```
$controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$location = $location;
})
```

I'd still go with calling method on the scope.

Comment: I think OP knows that: "I CAN get it working if I call a function in a controller"

Comment: cant we directly do ng-click="$location.path('/edit')" ? and inject $location service in the controller so that location service will be accessible in the view/ partials

Answer (score 11):

Few things to note here:

1. Referencing the Window in Angular expressions is disallowed!, so trying to use `$window.location.href = '/url'` on an inline `ng-click` expression will not work.
2. `$location` is not exposed automatically to your scope, you'll need to expose this to the view by injecting it first to the controller and then the scope.

   .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
       $scope.$loc = $location;
   })
3. It's worth noting that `$location.path()` & `$location.url()` will NOT redirect you to a new page, this is used for routing so that route callbacks/watchers can do it's thing. The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page.
4. The best (and also angular way imo) is to add a method to your scope in the controller. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API: `$window.location.href`.

Use a method bound to your controller:

```
$scope.redirect = function(url, refresh) {
    if(refresh || $scope.$$phase) {
        $window.location.href = url;
    } else {
        $location.path(url);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

And then call your method from your `ng-click` expression:

`<button ng-click="redirect('/')">GO HOME! NO BODY LOVES YOU</button>`

***Note:*** The above method will require you to inject both `$location` & `$window` to your controller.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use ng-href.

```
<button ng-href="http://example.com/login.jsp?un={{username}}&pw={{password}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Log In!</button>
```

Comment: How did you get this to work when `href` doesn't work with `button` elements?

Answer (score 0):

**This should definitely work**

```js
$scope.loadSchedules = function () {

        window.location.href = '/Admin/Admin/DoctorsSchedule';
        
    };


**Define a function inside "ng-click" attribute**
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary success" ng-click="loadSchedules()">Ok</button>
```

Comment: The questioner mentions this 'I CAN get it working if I call a function in a controller'. He is looking for other approaches