# How can I use ng-hide if $location.url == base (root) url?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I'd like a **← Back to home** link to appear below the nagivation on every page of my Angular app except the home page. So I'd like to conditionally add the link and hide it using `ng-hide` if the url is already on the home page (view) of the app.

I've tried using angular's `$location` service with no success

```
<p ng-hide="location.hash == '#/'" class="container"><a href="#topics">&larr; Back to Home</a></p>
```

I've tried the following variations:

```
ng-hide="location.hash == '#/' " //console.log shows true
ng-hide="location.hash === '#/' " //console.log shows true
ng-hide="location.hash == '' "    //console.log shows false
```

I'm puzzled because if I log the value of `location.hash == '#/'` when on the home page i get `true`, so `ng-hide` should work.

Basically I'm trying the 3rd approach listed here:
[How do I use angular ng-hide based on the page/route that I am currently on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338743/how-do-i-use-angular-ng-hide-based-on-the-page-route-that-i-am-currently-on) But it's not working. The other two approaches on that page seem overly complicated for what I'm trying to achieve.

What am I missing?

Comment: See this link for a similar question that was asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940320/how-to-redirect-using-ng-click

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First things first, when you use location.hash or location.url you are actually using the window.location javascript object, you should use the $location service provided by angular.
So in your controller I would create:

```
$scope.currentPath = $location.path();
```

And in your html:

```
<div ng-hide="currentPath === '/'"></div>
```

Tho I would be carefull about the "#/" and "/", I only use the html5 mode so I'm not sure what the $location.path will return but you can easily check it with a console.log($location.path()) tho I think it will only return "/" because that's the path for angular, it shouldn't care about the #.

Comment: Ah, that's the step I was missing! I wasn't assigning $location.path() to anything in my controller. Thanks to you both!!

Comment: It just missing a double-quote here `<div ng-hide="currentPath == '/'"></div>` (but can't edit just for one character :( )

Comment: @roxySka Thanks for that, I just edited the answer and also added the "exactly equal" check.

Comment: @Gino I guess that when your route changes you use a different controller, make sure all controllers have location in scope, or use a higher scope like rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is looking for a `$scope` variable called `location`.  If you want this to work you would have to do:

```
$scope.location = window.location
```

in your controller.  But then you should really inject `$location` and set `$scope.location = $location`